# Screen is black with mouse narrow

Tags: raspbian, ssh, operating-systems

I get a black screen on my Raspberry Pi. When I right clicked on the mouse, Scratch was opened, and when I closed the program my Raspberry shut down.

Please help me anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Could you give us some more details?
What display are you using? - Check the connection

What OS are you running? Try re-installing it.

What type of mouse are you using?

Do you see anything on startup?  Try pressing LSHIFT while your Pi is booting.

Comment: I am using sharp Lcd and after updateing my raspberry pi and booting i gat ablack screen but mouse is clear in the middle of screen and when i click on mouse scratch is opened , my mouse is hp , os is raspbian , i can't understand what is going on , thanks for your help

Comment: Can you press and hold Left Shift while booting until it opens something?